# SharpPDF for ASP.net core 2.2.x

Tags: sharppdf

I am trying to use SharpPDF with Asp.net core 2.2, I have "Install-Package HtmlRenderer.PdfSharp -Version 1.5.0.6", but when I try to access that page within my application that uses SharpPDF I get "Could not load file or assembly 'HtmlRenderer, Version=1.5.0.6" is this because SharpPDF does not support core?